# Get and observe three objects with Room/LiveData

Tags: android, transformation, android-room, relation, android-livedata

I have following database relationship:
[image]

In words: One `Order` has 0-n `Books`, one `Order` is assigned to one `Customer`.

In my case, I have `bookId`. **I want to launch some function when I get all associated items (Book, Order and Customer) and when I am assured all of them exists - I need to launch it only one time**. I tried to solve it following way:

ViewModel:

```
private LiveData<Book> book;
private LiveData<Order> order;
private LiveData<Customer> customer;

public MyViewModel(Application app) {
    ...
    book = bookRepository.getBookLiveData(id);
    order = Transformations.switchMap(book, b -> orderRepository.getOrder(b.getIdOrder()));
    customer = Transformations.switchMap(order, o -> customerRepository.getCustomer(o.getIdCustomer()));
}
```

However, this solution is uneffective and I believe this can be done some more elegant way with Room/LiveData.

I tried also another approach - creating following object `BookOrderCustomer`:

```
public class BookOrderCustomer {

    @Embedded
    public Book book;

    @Embedded
    public Order order;

    @Embedded
    public Customer customer;

}
```

But this did not work as expected,`Dao`'s query always returned null.

Any idea how to solve this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData#top_of_page), it could observe all your streams and merge data. I think this is a best approach.

Comment: How can I use `MediatorLiveData`, when those objects are not of the same class? Please provide some example code.

Comment: You could create wrapper object, which contains book, order, customer objects.

Comment: Here is an example https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/use-mediatorlivedata-to-query-and-merge-different-data-type/